# NSBlockOperation with Nested Completion Block

Tags: ios, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

Supposed to have a method with completion block to execute:

```
[container insert:data
               completion:^(NSDictionary *result, NSError *error) {

               }];
```

I need to make this concurrent using `NSOperation` (more than `GCD` dispatch block, since I need more control over operation flow and cancellation).

Now, assumed to execute a normal completion block I could use `NSBlockOperation` like

```
- (NSOperation *)executeBlock:(void (^)(void))block
                    inQueue:(NSOperationQueue *)queue
                    completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion
{
    NSOperation *blockOperation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:block];
    NSOperation *completionOperation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
        completion(blockOperation.isFinished);
    }];

    [completionOperation addDependency:blockOperation];

    [[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] addOperation:completionOperation];
    [queue addOperation:blockOperation];

    return blockOperation;
}
```

and so calling it like

```
[self executeBlock:^{
        /// my sync code

    }   inQueue:operationQueue
        completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }];
```

The problem instead having async code there:

```
void (^completionBlock)() = ^void() {
        // this is the NSOperation completion block where sync code is executed
    };
```

and

```
    void (^insertCompletionBlock)(NSDictionary *, NSError *) = ^void(NSDictionary *result, NSError *error) {
      // this is the insert api completion block 
   };
```

So having

```
[container insert:data completion:insertCompletionBlock];
```

If I do a nested call like

```
[self executeBlock:^{
    [container insert:data
           completion:^(NSDictionary *result, NSError *error) {

           }];

}   inQueue:operationQueue
    completion:^(BOOL finished) {

}];
```

this `NSOperation` will end immediately, since the `insert:completion:` method will return after its call having a completion block.

So, how to serialize this execution in order to have a `NSBlockOperation` called after the nested completion block of `insert:completion:` is executed?

**[UPDATED]**
Using the solution by @Mozilla
I came out with a custom `NSBlockOperation` that I used to add some properties on:

```
@interface MyCloudOperation: NSBlockOperation
@property(nonatomic,strong) id result;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSError *error;
@end
@implementation MXMCloudOperation
@end
```

and this

```
MyCloudOperation *blockOp=[[MyCloudOperation alloc] init];
    __weak MXMCloudOperation *weakBlockOp=blockOp;
    [blockOp setCompletionBlock:^{
        if(completion) completion(weakBlockOp.result,weakBlockOp.error);
    }];
    [blockOp addExecutionBlock:^{
        dispatch_semaphore_t mutex = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
        void (^insertCompletionBlock)(NSDictionary *, NSError *) = ^void(NSDictionary *result, NSError *error) {
            if(error) {
                weakBlockOp.error=error;
                NSLog(@"Error saving to %@ data\n%@", containerName,
                      error.localizedDescription);
            } else {
                weakBlockOp.result=result;
                NSLog(@"Data %@ sent", result);
            }
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(mutex);
        };
        [container insert:data completion:insertCompletionBlock];
        dispatch_semaphore_wait(mutex, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    }];
    [operationQueue addOperation:blockOp];
```

What I don't like here is to reference my `NSBlockOperation` to pass the completion handler's parameters, but I didn't find out a better solution right now.

Comment: Hi. Why do you not use the `completionBlock` property of the `NSOperation`? It will be automaticaly invoked after how operation will be finished. Before adding an operation to the `queue`, just set `completionBlock`.

Comment: The completion block of a ```NSBlockOperation``` is to notify that an operation is completed. But if the code to be executed has its own completion block, this will be called immediately, since your code is async, right?

Comment: I'm understand your issue. I solved this by using `dispatch_semaphore_t`. See this link for example [https://gist.github.com/Mozilla9/16b0b5013256ff89e52b](https://gist.github.com/Mozilla9/16b0b5013256ff89e52b)

Comment: @Mozilla That's correct, please post the answer so I can accept it!. I was trying the same solution using the ```dispatch_group_notify``` and ```dispatch_group_async```, but the only way is the ```dispatch_semaphore_t``` +1. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this by using `dispatch_semaphore_t`.

```
- (void)saveWebDataInternal:(ResponseModel *)data completion:(void(^)(NSArray *))completion
{
        NSBlockOperation *op = [[NSBlockOperation alloc] init];

        op.completionBlock = ^{
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self loadCachedDataInternal:completion];
            });
        };

        [op addExecutionBlock:^{
            dispatch_semaphore_t mutex = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

            [self.cacheDAO asyncImport:data completion:^{
                dispatch_semaphore_signal(mutex);
            }];

            dispatch_semaphore_wait(mutex, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
        }];

        // start operation
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            [op start];
        });
}
```

Comment: This could be further improved, supposed that I would like to pass parameters from the ```asyncImport``` completion to the ```saveWebDataInternal``` completion handlers, let's say an error and a result like ```(void(^)(id result, NSError *error))completion```. A solution could be using a custom ```NSBlockOperation``` to backed on, like in my example for the ```insert``` completion parameter. It's like when in Java you pass parameters to a ```Runnable``` thread in the constructor. Any better idea?

Comment: @loretoparisi Added a gist [https://gist.github.com/Mozilla9/1530db57f21f860821a2](https://gist.github.com/Mozilla9/1530db57f21f860821a2). It looks like your decision, but uses `__block` variables